# I would like a menu submenu using javascript or any other way possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've searched and tried multiple way to accomplish this to no avail...

i have provided my current code below....please feel free to critique and provide with any help necessary...

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
<p><a href="#" id="toggle">Leave A Note</a></p>
<ul id="menu">



<li><a href="/#" class="theengineer">Artist</a><ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="Sketchbook">Sketchbook</a></li><li><a href="#" class="Music">Music</a></li><li><a href="#" class="Artwork">Artwork</a></li><li>
    <a href="#" class="Media">Media</a></li><li><a href="#" class="Words">Words</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/#" class="theengineer">UI/UX Developer</a><ul><li><a href="#" class="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li><li><a href="#" class="resume">Resume</a></ul></li></div>

<!--above is the html container-->
<!--Now add javascript to control the hiding and such-->

<script>

var showMenuText = $('#toggle').text();
var hideMenuText = 'Close';

$('#navigation ul').hide();
$('#navigation ul a.active+ul').show();

hideMenu = function() {
    $('#navigation ul#menu').hide();
    $('#navigation').removeClass('Open');
    $('#toggle').text(showMenuText);
    }
    $('#toggle').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropogation(); event.preventDefault();
        $('#navigation ul#menu').toggle();
        $('#navigation').toggleClass('open');
        var toggleText = $('#toggle').text();

        (toggleText == showMenuText) ? $(this).text(hideMenuText) : $(this).text(showMenuText);});
        $('ul#menu > li > a').click(function(event){
            $this = $(this);
            if ($this.hasClass('page') ) parent.location = $this.attr('href');
            if ($this.hasClass('home') ) { parent.location = '/'; }

            event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();
            if( $this.hasClass('active') ) var justclosed = true;
            $('a.active').removeClass('active').next('ul').hide();
            if(!justclosed) $this.addClass('active').next('ul').show();
            });
            </script>
```

here

the javascript is not doing as what i expect it to..as the unordered lists are still showing as a list and are not hidden....any advice would be greatly appreciated!..

Comment: instead of re-inventing the wheel like this, you could try using [superfish](http://plugins.jquery.com/superfish/), a fantastic menu plugin based on jquery.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/9Hkxs/22/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/QapjP/)?

Comment: @SpYk3HH very nice :)

Comment: is there a way where i can render the sub menu's horizontal, instead of the default vertical display?

Comment: this doesn't work spyk3hh....is there a reason or something i am doing wrong...i copied the code you displayed in the jquery website...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing li at this line:

```
<li><a href="/#" class="theengineer">UI/UX Developer</a><ul><li><a href="#" class="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li><li><a href="#" class="resume">Resume</a></ul></li></div>
```

This should be

```
<li><a href="/#" class="theengineer">UI/UX Developer</a><ul><li><a href="#" class="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li><li><a href="#" class="resume">Resume</a></li></ul></li></div>
```

Maybe this is causing the javascript issue.

Comment: I believe the Li is supposed to be left open...as that line indicates the parent menu where sub menues are to follow...

Answer (score 0):

Drop Down menus can be done by Pure CSS with `relative` and `absolute` elements.
Consider the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Level 1</li>
    <li>
        Level 2
        <ul>
            <li>Level 2-1</li>
            <li>Level 2-2</li>
            <li>Level 2-3</li>
            <li>Level 2-4</li>
            <li>Level 2-5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 3</li>
    <li>Level 4</li>
    <li>Level 5</li>
</ul>
```

---

### Horizontal

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JTUdZ/)**

[image]

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: -1px;
    display: none;
}

ul ul li + li {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
}

ul li + li {
    margin-left: -1px;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: #b0e0e6;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

---

### Vertical

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JTUdZ/1/)**

[image]

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 150px;
    display: none;
}



ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid #4169e1;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
}

ul li + li {
    margin-top: -1px;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: #b0e0e6;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```